# Write pandas dataframe values to excel to specific cell in a specific sheet.

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
   Name    Sheet   Row  Column  Value
0  V1      Sheet1  1    1       89
1  V2      Sheet1  2    1       104
2  V3      Sheet2  1    2       6
3  V4      Sheet3  3    3       -5
```

I want to save the Value in the sheet, row and column specified in the dataframe. They are not in order and I don't know how many sheets there would be. I could just go through each row and write using xlwt package

```
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')

ws.write(1, 1, 89)
```

I was wondering if I could achieve this using pandas API or any better approach? Couldn't see pandas providing access to specific rows and columns of excel for writing.

Comment: You mean writing the value to the specific cell on excel sheet?

Comment: yes, to a specific cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an API which would directly write, however, I found `xlwings` module to be quite helpful and intutive. Used the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('out.xls')

for index, row in result.iterrows():
    wb.sheets[row['Sheet_Name']].range((row['Row'], row['Column'])).value = row['transformed_value']

wb.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is with the help of a for loop and `iterrows()` i.e

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx')
for _,i in df.iterrows():
    t_df = pd.DataFrame([i['Value']])
    t_df.to_excel(writer, startcol=i['Column'],startrow=i['Row'], sheet_name=i['Sheet'], header=None, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was hoping, I wouldn't have to iterate over the rows and just pass the cell index series, but I guess this also gets the job done!

Comment: @orak and I dont think this can be done without iterating since a cell has to be found from two different columns for every row to add the value. It would really be great if this can be done without iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Use slicing for the relevant rows/columns selection followed by the to_excel function to dump into an Excel sheet.

```
to_write_df =  ws[(ws['Row']==1) & (ws['Column']==1)]
to_write_df.to_excel('output_file_path')
```

[to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)