# python writing a df to a specific cell of excel

Tags: python, excel

I have come across a lot of answers and just wanted to check if this is the best answer
[Write pandas dataframe values to excel to specific cell in a specific sheet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389149/write-pandas-dataframe-values-to-excel-to-specific-cell-in-a-specific-sheet)

The question is - assuming I have a dataframe "df".
I want to write to an existing excel file called "Name1.xlsx", in
worksheet called "exampleNames", and starting at cell d25.

What's the easiest/ most efficient way to do that.

###############Updated!#############

I tried this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl


path = "C:\\Users\\ABC\\PycharmProjects\\ABC\\Name1.xlsx"

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(3,2)),columns=['a','b'])

df.to_excel(path,sheet_name="exampleNames",startcol=5,startrow=5,header=None,index=False)
df.to_excel(path,sheet_name="NN",startcol=5,startrow=25,header=None,index=False)
```

gave me error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach suggested in the [`pandas docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=col,startrow=row, header=None)
```

where writer could be path-like, file-like, or ExcelWriter object

eg

```
df.to_excel('sample.xlsx',sheet_name="exampleNames",startcol=5,startrow=5,header=None)
```

To save multiple dataframes in excel, you will have to use the writer object

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='exampleNames' ,startcol=5,startrow=5,header=None,index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NN', startcol=5,startrow=25,header=None,index=False)
```

Comment: thanks, that didnt work. snippets of my codes are in the main body. can you modify the code and get me what works your end?

Comment: Can you please install openpyxl

Comment: @Trex please use int values of row and column as well, do not use strings eg`df.to_excel('temp.xlsx',sheet_name="exampleNames",startcol=25,startrow=25,header=None)` this should work perfectly

Comment: actually, i did after the error msg. I get this error "    row=startrow + cell.row + 1, column=startcol + cell.col + 1
TypeError: must be str, not int"

Comment: can you make sure startrow and startcol indeed are int values

Comment: Can you post the exact code that you are trying with the above df as example

Comment: ok here is the thing, you code works but it deleted my other tabs from the excel. I have updated the codes above. how do I avoid other tabs getting deleted. Here I tried to upload to two tabs "exampleNames" and "NN" and the first tab got deleted.

Comment: so yes, looks like all other tabs got deleted on tab "NN" was left in the excel. Do you see same issue your end as well?

Comment: @TRex can you try my answer and let me know if it works for you

Comment: ok the same issue. if my excel has 5 tabs and I am writing to 2 of those tabs, then the other 3 gets deleted still.

Comment: you are creating the excel right? are you writing to an already existing excel?

Comment: no, its an already existing excel.

Comment: ok so here is the thing the tabs "exampleNames" and "NN" already exist in my file, along with many other tabs. I am not creating new tabs but updating existing tabs. Sorry if this was unclear in my original msg.

Comment: looks like your new codes are creating new tabs called "exampleNames" and "NN" in my excel. They just need to update existing tabs, without adding no new tabs.

Comment: so what are you getting currently when you are trying my code? data will be overwriteen obviously

Comment: yes, its creating "exampleNames1" and "NN1". And the data is in these two sheets. On a positive note - none of my sheets are getting deleted! :)

Comment: do you want to append the new dataframe in those existing tabs? I mean you already have say exampleNames and then you want the new data to be appended in the same sheet?

Comment: yes, so for eg. in tab "exampleNames", if I have data from row 1 column F to row 5. So I wanted my df from row 6 and columns F. So its just appending rows to the existing table. your codes are placing the data correctly - just need to not create a new tab and place in existing tab itself.

Comment: @TRex updated my answer please try again

Comment: nope still creating new sheets and putting values in them! but existing sheets are not deleted.

Comment: Sure pinged you!